# How to init google map inside my directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

After following a tutorial demo regarding google map and angularjs directive, I have the sample code with:

HTML

```
<map-geo-location height="400" width="600"></map-geo-location>
```

And the directive JS:

```
function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
           status = angular.element(document.getElementById('status'));
           mapContainer = angular.element(document.getElementById('map'));

           mapContainer.attr('style', 'height:' + scope.height +
                             'px;width:' + scope.width + 'px');
           $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mapLocation, geoError);
        }

          function mapLocation(pos) {
              status.html('Found your location! Longitude: ' + pos.coords.longitude +
                          ' Latitude: ' + pos.coords.latitude);

              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,
                                                  pos.coords.longitude);
              var options = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

              var map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer[0], options);

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title:"Your location"
              });
        }

return {
           scope: {
               height: '@',
               width: '@'
           },
           link: link,
           template: template
        };
```

However, I noticed that, if I do NOT want to load current geoLocation and just want to load map with some given coordinates, the map is not loaded.

Why is that? Is it caused by any aync call? If so, could to address it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just remove the geo get location statement, and ensure the following is invoked directly inside the link() function.